# P4Eclipse allows me to edit file without checking it out

Tags: eclipse, perforce, p4eclipse

I installed P4Eclipse plugin in Eclipse. However, I noticed that Eclipse allows me to edit a file, but it doesn't automatically check it out from Perforce repository. So, after I edited the file, then go to P4V, the recently modified file won't show up in default change set. Any suggestion on what to look into here?

Thanks.

Comment: If I grab a file directly from my local workstation stored in my Perforce workspace and attempt to edit and save I get a warning that the file is read only, it doesnt stop me from editing, just from saving.  To make an association with the server version of the file it needs to be checked out first...IF you are able to edit (and save those files to the work space directory that is a problem.  Can you confirm that is what is happening?

Comment: Actually, after some investigation, I realized that this is indeed related to file system read/write permission. For other reason, I accidentally changed sources files in my perforce workspace to readable. This is why I get to modify them in eclipse without seeing a warning, and at the same time Perforce doesn't realize that these file have been changed.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, after some investigation, I realized that this is indeed related to file system read/write permission. For other reason, I accidentally changed sources files in my perforce workspace to readable. This is why I get to modify them in eclipse without seeing a warning, and at the same time Perforce doesn't realize that these file have been changed.

Manually fixing the permission on those source files resolved this problem.